# Pdf.js Blank page and the end

Tags: javascript, pdf, printing, pdf.js

we have this problem in PDF.js where every PDF which we try to print. On preview we see correct number of pages but when we print it out, it prints one extra page and we don't know why it is.

[Link to our example PDF](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6dj7ew27dseo7bn/Test_Test_20_06_2017.pdf?dl=0)

**Configuration:**

- Web browser and its version: Integrated in Electron App and tested on
  Chrome Version 59.0.3071.104
- Operating system and its version: Windows 10 ver. 1703
- PDF.js version: 1.7.225 (Stable), we tried even Beta (1.8.188) or
  built latest repo

I don't know why it's happening. I tried change print styles, resolution, explored issues on Github, even modified PDF but nothing helped. Interesting is that one of our PDFs prints as it is so I don't get what's happening.

Comment: Have you logged this issue with the creators on github?

Comment: Yes I logged it 6 days ago and no response :-(

Comment: I'm not sure this is something we can help with. I'd wait for a response by the pdf.js team.

Comment: I thought so...